# how to index to data with various data types?

Tags: c

I have datas with various data types.

For example, datas are like below.

data1 : uint8
data2 : int32
data3 : uint8 a[100] …

And I want to refer to the datas with an index.

If index=1, i get data1.
And if index=2, i get data2.

Because of data types are different,
I failed to use array or structs as below.

```
UINT8 a[num] = {data1,data2,data3};
```

or

```
struct data{
UINT8 data;
};
```

how can i do this?
Is there any good way to deal woth various data type?

Comment: C doesn't have any kind of container or other structure that is both indexable and heterogeneous. What is the *actual* and *underlying* problem you need to solve this way? What makes you think this is the only possible solution? Please always ask about the actual problem you have, instead of making it an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and only ask for help to the solution to (for us) the unknown problem.

Comment: C generally uses `void *` to point to unknown data.

Comment: Depending on why you actually need this, you may try luck with `union`s.

Comment: Are you talking about deserializing incoming protocol data? Or do you internally store such a mixed size thingy?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes, my application is data management function. so i need to keep many datas with various size and type

Comment: That sounds like you want to store the data in flexible way, not only transfer it wie some connection and then unpack it again. Then it is not about serializing.

Comment: @Gerhardh I am not doing some communication, but just some data managament thing as eeprom function

Comment: Do you want to know how to unpack the data from EEPROM into a struct? Do you want to handle with such data in RAM? Do you know the fields or do you need to deal with generic data that you can't control?

Comment: There are for sure multiple solutions, so this is a question that leads to opinions. You might need to do some research on your own, and to enhance your question, focussing on issues according to "[ask]". --  For example, do you want to incorporate some kind of directory, that can be accessed by indexes? Or do you want to use a linked list? Is the number of entries fixed, and the sizes of the entries? If not, how do you tackle memory limits?

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef union
{
    uint8_t  b8[sizeof(uint64_t) / sizeof(uint8_t)];
    uint16_t b16[sizeof(uint64_t) / sizeof(uint16_t)];
    uint32_t b32[sizeof(uint64_t) / sizeof(uint32_t)];
    uint32_t b64[sizeof(uint64_t) / sizeof(uint64_t)];
}data_t;
```

Safe:

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char data[] =  {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,10,11,12,13,14,15};

    data_t d[sizeof(data) / sizeof(data_t) + 1];

    memcpy(d, data, sizeof(data));

    /* .... */
```

unsafe:

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char data[] =  {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,10,11,12,13,14,15};

    data_t *d = (data_t *)data;
    /*...*/
```

Comment: why `uint8_t  b8[sizeof(uint64_t) / sizeof(uint16_t)]`?

Comment: @stark ovious typo